# Setting the delegate of a UITextField/UITableView inside a Custom UIView to the managing ViewController

Tags: ios, uiview, delegates

I have a `CustomView` `UIView` class that represents my `screenUI` in which I programatically create and position the UI elements, among which multiple UITextFields and a UITableView.
I also have a `UIViewController` and in it's loadView which I assign my CustomView to self.view.

I do this in order to best keep the cohesion of the view and the controller.

My question is how can I set the delegate of the `UITextFields` and `UITableView` inside the CustomView to the managing `UIViewController`?

It is my understanding that the `UITextFieldDelegate` and all other protocol methods should be implemented in the Controller and not the View, but I would like to avoid setting the delegate of the items in the view controller (e.g. `textField1.delegate = self` in the `UIViewController` class instead of `textField1.delegate = <value` for setting UIViewController as delegate> in my `CustomView` class) in order to keep my code cleaner.

Thank yous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a `delegate` property on your custom view:

```
customView.delegate = self;
self.view = customView;
```

In the delegate setter you could forward responsibilities:

```
-(void) setDelegate:(id<*the protocols you need*>) del
{
     _textField.delegate = del;
     ...
}
```

You could have more than 1 type of delegate on your custom view, it depends on you needs, but one implementing all the protocols should usually suffice.

Comment: Thank you, I think this way makes it look cleaner.

Comment: Be wary that this is very tightly coupled and requires ALL your delegates to be the same object leaving little room in the future for good data separation. It is much prettier though ;)

Comment: You make a valid point and I'm convinced that your answer is the way to go in general, but for this particular project I need all of the delegates to be the same object. Thanks again.

Comment: Actually, he can have multiple delegates on the custom view too, eg one for all text fields one for the table view, I've already mentioned that.

Comment: Also, your method goes against good encapsulation Ryan, you advise to have as many delegates as textfields, while the custom object is an entity of it own, which tries to encapsulate them all and hide the complexity of working with them from the controller.

Comment: Encapsulation is one of the reason for which Apple always sends the instance that triggered the delegate message along in the protocol method: '-(void)tableview:(UITableView *) tableview ...'

Comment: Regarding good encapsulation, how would I go about handling button methods? Is setting it's target as self and making the selector call the method in the ViewController enforced by a CustomViewDelegate the best way?

Answer (score 0):

I would probably just forward them along. Create properties representing the delegates on your custom view. then in loadView set them to self.

```
// CustomView.h
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <UITextFieldDelegate> textFieldDelegate;
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <UITableViewDatasource> tableViewDataSource;
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <UITableViewDelegate> tableViewDelegate;

// Create textField
textField.delegate = self.textFieldDelegate;

// in ViewController
- (void)loadView
{
    CustomView *view = //...
    view.textFieldDelegate = self;
}
```

Comment: Well, as I said, I am preferably looking for a solution where I don't have to make any assignments in the ViewControllers loadView method, but this one looks pretty neat.
Apart from the controls visibility, is there any difference to just assigning delegates like this:
`view.textField1.delegate = self`

Comment: No that would work. However it is a bit tighter connection. So if you wanted to swap out a textfield you'd have to change the controller instead of just swapping the customView's property value. But technically it will work just the same.

Comment: The other way that is SUPER overkill is to create a delegate for your customView and only forward specific calls maybe even grouped if it makes sense.

Comment: I actually do have a delegate created for my CustomView because I have some methods to be done for a couple of Buttons but because it has different functionality than the UITextFieldDelegate & co. I didn't think I should implement those protocols in my custom one.

Comment: Well I wouldn't just forward the protocols. I'd just create new ones for your CustomView then do what needs to be done. So you may have an update CustomView protocol method and in that method you update your textField and tableView rather than separating out their delegates. Its very possible that won't work in your setup.